Recognizing special unicode characters in lualatex
I'm having trouble with the symbols 〚 and 〛which in math mode are called \llbracket and \rrbracket respectively.
I would like it if my LuaLatex could recognize these symbols the same way it does with many others. At the moment only a blank space shows up in their place.
I'm using the unicode-math package.
Let me know if I should add something else to the question.

Edit.
Excuse me everyone! It seems I wasn't clear.
If I type \llbracket or \rrbracket, it displays properly.
What I want is to type the unicode symbols 〚 or 〛 in math mode, in the textfile, and get the usual math symbols for \llbracket and \rrbracket respectively on the pdf.
In general I have had no problems with any other unicode symbol. If I type $α×σ$, it displays the same as if I had typed $\alpha\times\sigma$.
But the same is not happening when typing 〚 or 〛, it just displays a blank space instead.

"At the moment only a blank space shows up in their place." Your log file must also contain a couple of warning messages, about \llbracket and \rrbracket not being recognized. Don't disregard such warning messages.

Please tell us which TeX distribution employ and when it was last updated.

The default math font under pdfLaTeX, called Computer Modern Math, does not natively provide the symbols 〚 and 〛. This makes it necessary to take an extra step -- usually in the form of loading a suitable LaTeX package -- to access these two symbols.
According to The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List, which currently lists more than 20,000 [!] symbols and their associated LaTeX macro names,  \llbracket and \rrbracket are the names of macros provided by the stmaryd and fourier packages, for use in math mode. In addition, the fdsymbol, nath, and stix packages provide macros named \lBrack and \rBrack to access the two symbols, also for use in math mode. Finally, the textcomp package provides the commands \textlbrackdbl and \textrbrackdbl, for use in text mode. (Aside: If you are using a reasonably up-to-date (La)TeX distribution, it's no longer necessary to load the textcomp package explicitly in order to access the symbols it defines.)
Now, since you're using LuaLaTeX and the unicode-math package to compile your document, you should use the macro names \lBrack and \rBrack, as they are provided directly by the unicode-math package without the need to load any of the packages mentioned in the preceding paragraph. If you've already been using \llbracket and \rrbracket in your document and for some reason are unable or unwilling to switch to using \lBrack and \rBrack, you could issue the instruction
\AtBeginDocument{\NewCommandCopy{\llbracket}{\lBrack}%
                 \NewCommandCopy{\rrbracket}{\rBrack}}

in the preamble of your document to keep using \llbracket and \rrbracket. Many thanks to @egreg for suggesting this instruction.
By typing texdoc unimath-symbols at a command prompt, you may access the full set of symbols defined by the unicode-math package, the associated LaTeX macro names, and a tabulation of which of 11 math fonts explicitly supported by unicode-math provide which symbols. According to the unimath-symbols document, 10 of the 11 supported math fonts -- the exception being Fira Math -- currently supply glyphs for \lBrack and \rBrack.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
% If desired, issue a suitable '\setmathfont' directive. (The
% default math font of unicode-math is 'Latin Modern Math'.)

\begin{document}
$\lBrack \dots \rBrack$
\end{document}


Better: \AtBeginDocument{\NewCommandCopy{\llbracket}{\lBrack}\NewCommandCopy{\rrbracket}{\rBrack}}

@egreg - Many thanks for this suggestion. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! Unfortunately it seems I hadn't made myself clear in the original question. I have edited it now. Cheers.

@Julián - Which vintage of LuaTeX and which version of unicode-math do you use? The reason I ask is that on my system (MacTeX2024 with all updates applied, LuaHBTeX Version 1.18.0, LaTeX2e 2024-06-01 patch level 2, and unicode-math version 2023/08/13 v0.8r), entering $⟦ . ⟧$ directly results in "⟦.⟧" being typeset.

@Mico This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.13.0 (Web2C 2021/nixos.org)  is what my terminal says. That might be it then.

@Julián - Any chance you could update your TeX distribution? Or, could you give your code a try on Overleaf (which also runs TeXLive2024) to verify that using a newer TeX distribution will get the job done?

Does overleaf run lualatex? Nix thinks it's updated, I wouldn't know what to do in this situation.

@Julián - Once you're logged in to Overleaf and have opened a tex file (or otherwise commenced a "project", click on the "Menu" button in the upper-right corner, go down to the "Compiler" row, and select "LuaLaTeX" from the drop-down menu to the right. (The default compiler, unsurprisingly, is pdfLaTeX.)

@Mico Is there possibly an adhoc way to solve this? Say I want some other unicode to be interpreted as some arbitrary latex code, e.g: say I want 〖 to be interpreted as \begin and 〗 as \end.

@Julián - This sounds like an essentially new question, rather than a simple continuation of the ongoing question. Please post a new query when you have a new question.
